# Facebook does not send sms register as a developer

Tags: facebook

I want to use facebook api and thats whay I have to get a access token . I try to 10 times 2 different phone but facebook doesnt send confirmation code. how can I fixed?

Comment: Ask facebook, not us.

Answer (score 3):

You can try contacting Facebook using this form here -https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/338822979524831

Also, do check if you entered a valid country code.